# How to parse a string of xml in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, parsexml

Hi I have an xml mentioned below that comes as a string value  from the database. I want to parse the xml string and do not want to save the ones that has  empty space i.e   this statement means it stores empty space. I need to look for this statement in if condition and not save if empty space. Please let me know how to do that. Below is the vb.net code after the xml

```
<DocumentElement>
  <TBLCustomizedCodes>
    <tblRowkey>-1</tblRowkey>
    <TBLRowCustomizedCodes>test</TBLRowCustomizedCodes>
    <TBLRowCompliance>N/A</TBLRowCompliance>
  </TBLCustomizedCodes>
  <TBLCustomizedCodes>
    <tblRowkey>-2</tblRowkey>
    <TBLRowCustomizedCodes xml:space="preserve">      </TBLRowCustomizedCodes>
    <TBLRowCompliance xml:space="preserve">      </TBLRowCompliance>
  </TBLCustomizedCodes>
  <TBLCustomizedCodes>
    <tblRowkey>-3</tblRowkey>
    <TBLRowCustomizedCodes xml:space="preserve">      </TBLRowCustomizedCodes>
    <TBLRowCompliance xml:space="preserve">      </TBLRowCompliance>
  </TBLCustomizedCodes>
</DocumentElement>
```

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("DocumentElement")
        ds.Tables.Add(tempdataTable)

        Dim valueXML As String = ds.GetXml().ToString().Trim()
        SaveInspectionSupplementalLineItem(valueXML)
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to read the xml string as mentioned above and look for <TBLRowCustomizedCodes xml:space="preserve">    </TBLRowCustomizedCodes> which stores a empty space infact empty textbox in the front end. I donot want to call SaveInspectionSupplementalLineItem(valueXML) if empty textbox or space mentioned  as in the above xml statement. Please let me know how to do that

Comment: @dbasnett - I am trying to read the xml string as mentioned above and look for <TBLRowCustomizedCodes xml:space="preserve"> </TBLRowCustomizedCodes> which stores a empty space infact empty textbox in the front end. I donot want to call SaveInspectionSupplementalLineItem(valueXML) if empty textbox or space mentioned as in the above xml statement. Please let me know how to do that

Comment: see my answer. XElement and LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)` to check if it's empty before saving it

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("DocumentElement")
ds.Tables.Add(tempdataTable)

Dim valueXML As String = ds.GetXml().ToString().Trim()
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueXML) Then
    SaveInspectionSupplementalLineItem(valueXML)
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work because I am looking for <TBLRowCustomizedCodes xml:space="preserve">      </TBLRowCustomizedCodes> this statement stores blank space means a blank textbox in the front end so I need to get hold of this tag in xml and when it is empty it should not save

Comment: If you wish to select a single node and check if the value is empty you could use `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode({node path}).InnerText`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    Dim valueXML As String = ds.GetXml() '.ToString() '??? 
    xe = XElement.Parse(valueXML)
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From el In xe.Descendants Where el.Value.Trim = "" Select el
    If ie.Count > 0 Then
        'there WERE Elements with empty space
        Stop 'look at ie.Results
    Else
        'no empties
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps.